# Magento 2.2.5 : Runtime Exception during setup:di:compile

Tags: magento-2.2.5, setup-di-compile, production-mode, dicompilation

The issue started when I was attempting to enter production mode with

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production
```

Upon researching the issue, I attempted to see if the error gave more information when I tried to compile without entering production mode.

Here is the error I received.

[image: error message]

Any thoughts on the next steps I can take to resolve this? The ultimate goal is to be able to switch to production mode, but this compiling issue seems to be what is preventing me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error during interceptor generation then this class should be referenced somewhere and doesn't actually exist.
I think you may not have created object of this class that's why you don't know where the error is coming from. So, first you should search for the mention class and remove it's reference.

If you only need to set the store in production you can also just skip compilation by adding --skip-compilation param like below ;

```
php bin/magento deploy:mode:set production --skip-compilation
```

Comment: Your answer gave me a step in the right direction. I was able to resolve my issue.

I simply disabled the MGS_Brand Module within the config.php file located at app/etc/config.php. 

After I disabled that, I attempted to compile once again and this time it successfully went through. I was also able to switch to production mode.

Comment: Glad to hear that, you can mark the answer as accepted if it helped.